# Moovweb: Getting Privacy Error when Moving from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: http, ssl, https, moovweb

I am transfering a website and when am navigating to a page my url is changing from HTTP to HTTPS. Here am getting the Privacy Error message in my browser.

How can I avoid this in moovweb transformation?

Let’s take the example of http://mlocal.erin.ne.jp/

When we are choosing Japanese version its pointing to https://mlocal.erin.ne.jp/jp but in my browser when its moving to secure site am getting Private error.

How can we set-up the config to avoid such error?

I tried with ssl_whitelist but no luck :(

```
{
  "host_map": [
    "$.erin.ne.jp => www.erin.ne.jp"
  ],
  "ssl_whitelist": [
  "erin.ne.jp",
  "erin.ne.jp/jp",
  "https://erin.ne.jp/jp"
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 2):

The `ssl_whitelist` configuration option is only necessary if the website you are trying to transform has invalid certificates. Typically, this might be a staging website where it is known that the certificates are invalid. So this option is unrelated to the problem you are seeing.

During local development, the Moovweb SDK will load a self-signed SSL certificate for the local domain. This is provided as a convenience to simulate SSL traffic.

When you hit https://mlocal.erin.ne.jp, that is your local server with invalid SSL certificates. Because there is no chain back to a root certificate authority, your browser will not trust the certificate.

If you acknowledge the error, you will be able to proceed. I am only recommending this because this is a local development situation only. During normal web browsing, take care when you see similar messages.

This is completely separate from production-ready projects that will be hosted on the Moovweb cloud. In production, you will have to acquire valid SSL certificates that matches the production domain name you select (typically m.erin.ne.jp, t.erin.ne.jp, or www.erin.ne.jp for a single-domain project). Once this is set up properly, you will not see any SSL certificate errors on your production domain.